# ArrayList becoming huge in program to guess number between 1000-9999

Tags: java, arraylist

The program guesses a number between 1000-9999 and the user says how many numbers of the guess are the right number and in the right spot (but only inputs the amount of correct numbers). However, every time I try it, I get a huge list of duplicates but only one entry of the correct number. How would I go about making sure there are no duplicates in my ArrayList? I'd prefer being pointed in the right direction and not just given the answer, thanks! Here is my code (main method was written by my professor and I shouldn't need to change it):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GuessingGame {

    public int numGuesses = 0;
    public ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public int guess;

    public GuessingGame ( ) {
        for (int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
        //populating numbers ArrayList

    }

    public int myGuessIs() {
        numGuesses++;
        //increases number of guesses
        int tempIndex = (int) (Math.random() * numbers.size());
        int myguess = numbers.get(tempIndex);
        //creates a new guess
        guess = myguess;
        //sets global variable
        return myguess;
    }

    public int totalNumGuesses() {
        return numGuesses;
        //returns guesses needed to reach solution
    }

    public void updateMyGuess(int nmatches) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> temp2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int first = guess/1000;
        int second = (guess/100)%10;
        int third = (guess/10)%10;
        int fourth = guess%10;
        //variables for each digit of guess
        if (nmatches == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
                if (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
                if ((numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
                if ((numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
                if (numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
            numbers.clear();
            numbers.addAll(temp);
        }else if (nmatches == 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
                if (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first &&
                    (numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
                if (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first &&
                    (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
                if (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first &&
                    numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
                if ((numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second &&
                    (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
                if ((numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second &&
                    numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
                if ((numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third &&
                    numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
            numbers.clear();
            numbers.addAll(temp);
        }else if (nmatches == 3) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
                if (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first && (numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second
                    && (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
                if (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first && (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third
                    && numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
                if ((numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second && (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third
                    && numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
            numbers.clear();
            numbers.addAll(temp);
        }else {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
                if (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first) temp2.add(numbers.get(i));
                if ((numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second) temp2.add(numbers.get(i));
                if ((numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third) temp2.add(numbers.get(i));
                if (numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) temp2.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
            numbers.removeAll(temp2);
        }
        //creates new smaller ArrayList with better guesses
        //sets numbers as the smaller list
        //update the guess based on the number of matching digits claimed by the user
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(numbers.get(i) + "   " + i);
        } //troubleshooting

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        GuessingGame gamer = new GuessingGame( );

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Think of a number between 1000 and 9999.\n Click OK when you are ready...", "Let's play a game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        int numMatches = 0;
        int myguess = 0;

        do {
            myguess = gamer.myGuessIs();
            if (myguess == -1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I don't think your number exists.\n I could be wrong though...", "Mistake", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I guess your number is " + myguess + ". How many digits did I guess correctly?");
            // quit if the user input nothing (such as pressed ESC)
            if (userInput == null)
                System.exit(0);
            // parse user input, pop up a warning message if the input is invalid
            try {
                numMatches = Integer.parseInt(userInput.trim());
            }
            catch(Exception exception) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your input is invalid. Please enter a number between 0 and 4", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                numMatches = 0;
            }
            // the number of matches must be between 0 and 4
            if (numMatches < 0 || numMatches > 4) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your input is invalid. Please enter a number between 0 and 4", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                numMatches = 0;
            }
            if (numMatches == 4)
                break;
            // update based on user input
            gamer.updateMyGuess(numMatches);

        } while (true);

        // the game ends when the user says all 4 digits are correct
        System.out.println("Aha, I got it, your number is " + myguess + ".");
        System.out.println("I did it in " + gamer.totalNumGuesses() + " turns.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a global? Why are you guessing completely randomly?

Comment: I'm making a random guess using the entries in the ArrayList I reduce

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ArrayList` use a Data Structure that does not allow for duplicates: a `Set`.

Comment: I don't think I'm supposed to use a set because we haven't learned those yet

Comment: ArrayList is a collection, you can check if it already contains the value. It will be slower than a set, but will behave the way you want

Answer (score 0):

Modify your procedure `updateMyGuess` as shown here. The numbers of array `numbers` that match the random number should be added only once in the temporary array and this is achieved by concatenating the `if`s with the Or operator:`||` Thus duplicates are avoided.

```
public void updateMyGuess(int nmatches) {
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> temp2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int first = guess/1000;
    int second = (guess/100)%10;
    int third = (guess/10)%10;
    int fourth = guess%10;
    //variables for each digit of guess
    if (nmatches == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            if (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first ||
               (numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second || 
               (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third ||
                numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
        }
        numbers.clear();
        numbers.addAll(temp);
    }else if (nmatches == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            if ((numbers.get(i)/1000 == first && (numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second) ||
                (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first && (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third)  ||
                (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first &&  numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) ||
               ((numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second && (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third) ||
                ((numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second && numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) ||
                (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third && numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
        }
        numbers.clear();
        numbers.addAll(temp);
    }else if (nmatches == 3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            if ((numbers.get(i)/1000 == first && (numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second
                && (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third) ||
               (numbers.get(i)/1000 == first && (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third
                && numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth) ||
               ((numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second && (numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third
                && numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth)) temp.add(numbers.get(i));
        }
        numbers.clear();
        numbers.addAll(temp);
    }else {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            if ((numbers.get(i)/1000 == first) ||
             ((numbers.get(i)/100)%10 == second) ||
             ((numbers.get(i)/10)%10 == third) ||
             (numbers.get(i)%10 == fourth)) temp2.add(numbers.get(i));
        }
        numbers.removeAll(temp2);
    }
    //creates new smaller ArrayList with better guesses
    //sets numbers as the smaller list
    //update the guess based on the number of matching digits claimed by the user
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(numbers.get(i) + "   " + i);
    } //troubleshooting

}
```